# Magento 2 - how to set a message for the customer cart page after removing cart items via cronjob

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1, messages

I have made a cronjob that removes items from customer cart after a specific time has passed and the customer hasn't checked out.

Now I need to set a message for the customer to see when he / she comes back to the cart page, explaining that such items have been removed due to timeout.

Since the cron runs outside the customer session, I cant just use the messages Manager to add a message. How could I do that?